# Product attributes not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, magento, attributes

I have a typical situation with me
I created many new attributes for products but whenever I edit those attributes like say a drop down, it doesn't open.
only if I click on text of drop down it will open else drop down will not open.
Same case is for date attributes. Clicking on calendar will not open the calendar.
But if I open the developer tools in browser, all behave normally.
Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check for any errors logged to the developer tools console?

Comment: Null
Everything is null
no error no js error!! :(

Comment: Clear your browser cache and cookies. Also clear css & js cache of magento.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I don't think it is off topic because there is some error related to programming only and I am expecting someone having same issue before so that he can help me out .